# Excel 2010 - When I paste a copied cell, why is it in quotations and missing the line breaks?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a strange issue whereby when I paste data from copied cells from excel in to NotePad++, it puts the data inside quotations and misses the line breaks that are in the cell.

I am creating the copy range (although I have tried manually copying one cell) form a VBA script that also adds the data to the cells.

Here is the code incase it helps:

```
Sub Ready_For_Infra()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long, lastcol As Long, g As Long
    Dim str1 As String

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("InfraData")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("ActionPlan")

    ws1.Cells.Clear

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    With ws2
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lastcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1
            str1 = ""
            For Each cell In .Range(.Cells(i, 6), .Cells(i, lastcol))
                g = i - 1
                If cell.Column <> 4 And cell.Column <> 5 And cell.Value <> "" And cell.Value <> "NEW ACTION" Then str1 = str1 & cell.Value & Chr(10) & "(" & cell.Offset(-g, 0).Value & ")" & Chr(10)
            Next cell
            ws1.Range("A" & 2 + lastrow - i).Value = ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & ws2.Cells(i, 2).Value & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & str1
        Next i
    End With

    ws1.Range("A2", "A" & lastrow).Copy

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

MsgBox "Done"


End Sub
```

The pasted data should look like this:

```
1

Testing1

Another Day of testing
(05/03/2014)
```

But instead looks like this:

```
"1Testing1AnotherDayoftesting(05/03/2014)"
```

However, when I paste it in to here, it appeared to include the line breaks and spaces but still include the quotations. (See Below)

```
"1

Testing1

Another Day of testing
(05/03/2014)
"
```

Comment: I think Chr(10) & Chr(10) should be Chr(13) & Chr(10)  (two times)

Comment: I just tried it and `Chr(10)` or `VbLf` is enough to change line, no need for carriage return `Chr(13)` or `VbCr`.

Comment: I just use control + v to paste it. However, in word it only puts the quotations round the data if you select paste text only. All other paste options remove the quotes and all keep the line breaks.

Comment: I am going to leave this Question "open" as it would be nice to know if anyone else finds another way to resolve this issue. However, I have overcome this by pasting each cell in to the correct format in a txt file and then copying the entire contents of that file instead. This removes the quotes and keeps the basic formatting.

Answer (score 0):

To get around leaving the quotes out when pasting from Excel to Notepad or others, I use the code below to put stuff in the clipboard:

```
Dim obj As New DataObject
obj.SetText NameofYourVariable
obj.PutInClipboard
```

It then pastes nicely without any double quotes.

Comment: Hi! Please format your code! See help section to know how to do it